# Are R & L-values relative to its context?

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

so assume we write the following in C++: `a=b=5;` which basically means `a=(b=5);`

If we have `a=5;` I know that 5 is a literal and thus it is an R-Value. `a` is an L-Value. Same goes for `b=5;`

I'm wondering now, what happens, if we write `a=b=5;` respectively `a=(b=5);`

Can I now say the following?

For `a`, `b=5` is an R-Value with `a` being an L-Value. Also, `b` is an L-Value and `5` is an R-Value.

What's the R-Value of `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends.  The built in `operator=` returns an lvalue reference to the left hand side of the assignment.  So, if `a` and `b` are `int`'s then `(b = 5)` is an lvalue expression and you assign that lvalue to `a`, with `a` and `b` both being lvalues and `5` being a prvalue.

This is generally the same for overloaded `operator=` as well since most people return a lvalue reference but it does not have to be.

If you want to cast a lvalue into a rvalue then you use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).